# Azure AD Global + Germany -One domain

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

If a there is an already established Azure Active Directory for Global, then a need in Germany is created, a new Active Directory needs to be setup there due to the laws in Germany. Therefore a new Azure AD must be created for these users. As it is a standalone entity, it is not connected to the Global, thus has no access to the resources of global.

Therefore, the question goes as follows;

1. Could Azure AD Global and Azure AD Germany have the same domain name ? If so, how?
2. Could Azure AD Global and Azure AD Germany share the same external applications?
3. If they can't use the same domain name, how can the Germany AD be connected to the "global" or rest of the company ?
4. If none of these are possible, how could Azure AD Global be used to safely and securely create an new instance or onsite Azure AD using the global AAD in Germany, that would use the same domain name as the Global and have the security required as per german law?

Answer (score 0):

1. no this is not possible, because they need to be globally routable, so you can't use the same domain for 2 different tenants. in addition, azure ad cannot be moved between regions.
2. No this is also not possible, because you need application registrations / service principals and they are specific to to a tenant. However you could use azure B2B to give the germany users access to the global tenant to access the external applications through that. however, this sometimes depends on the external app vendor whether or not they can be configured to do so, but normally its possible.
3. Again, you can use azure B2B to give Access to various resources between the two tenants. the issue with this is you have to create guest users for eachothers domains in each tenant in order to access their resources. there is something in public preview called direct federation for b2b, but I don't think it would accomplish what you're trying to do.
4. there is really no such thing as on-site azure ad. you could theoretically create a hybrid environment with on-premise ad domains and sync them to the same global azure ad tenant. however I don't think this would meet the security requirements as it would still be a single global tenant in the cloud. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies#multiple-forests-single-azure-ad-tenant here are the available topologies when using azure ad connect for hybrid.

to conclude, the most realistic solution is basically create a completely separate tenant in Germany, create users, and use B2B to invite users to collaborate using applications in the global tenant. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/compare-with-b2c
it will be a hassle to manage, it also depends on what you are trying to share. sometimes external applications let you have multiple sso profiles, in which case you don't need any of that, just have 2 completely separate tenants, and set up an sso profile to each in the external application.

Answer (score 0):

@alphaz18

I don't think B2B works between Germany and Global:

"Customers in Azure Germany cannot access resources that require a subscription or identity in global Azure."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/germany/germany-services-securityandidentity

I am currently bumping my head into these types of issues with Guests that want to register in a global tenant, but their identity is in the German tenant, and it doesn't work for them, it fails immediately.

Comment: Please post comments like this as comments to other answers. This is not an answer to the original question.